# Connect Ubuntu 11.04 to xbox 360

Tags: ubuntu, media, ubuntu-11.04, xbox360

I'd like to be able to stream .avi files to my xbox 360 video library.  I've gone through a bunch of different servers (ushare, xbmc) both from the aptitude and from source.  It seems that I can get the servers working from both localhost and from another computer on the network.  However, the xbox cannot detect any of these.  Can anybody give me a hand or perhaps post a detailed walkthrough to give me a hand?

Answer (score 1):

The XBMC FAQ contains some info on setups that are supposed to work:

http://wiki.xbmc.org/index.php?title=UPnP_Sharing

I haven't used ushare so can't comment, but for one I have used and I know works well, try installing Serviio on your server - it's quick and simple. If this doesn't work then there's something up elsewhere (firewall on Linux box?)

***Serviio - free DLNA media server***

*Serviio is a free DLNA media server. It allows you to stream your media files (music, video or images) to any DLNA-certified renderer device (e.g. a TV set, Bluray player, games console) on your home network.*

*Serviio works with any DLNA compliant device (TV, Playstation 3, etc.) and some other (XBox 360). It supports profiles for particular devices so that it can be tuned to maximise the device's potential and/or minimize lack of media format playback support (via transcoding).*

http://www.serviio.org/

Comment: I got ushare working kind-of.  The problem seems to be in the firewall.  I used lsof -i and opened up all of the ports ushare is using and it still doesn't work.  Any ideas?