# Only video playback not working for Xbox using uShare

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, dlna, xbox360, libav

I have been mucking around with video encode for a while now using Handbrake without any success.  (just recently tried EncodeHD on a Windows machine with no luck)  So far all music and pictures play well through uShare to my XBox 360.  I am able to get some of my videos to play on the XBox (using Skifta) that were recorded by my phone but in very crummy quality.

So far I have tried an xbox.plist file found at
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1350522 or by checkout out the uShare tag 0.9.3 to extract resources.plist - still no luck.

Here is a similar superuser posting - [Connect Ubuntu 11.04 to xbox 360](https://superuser.com/questions/301965/connect-ubuntu-11-04-to-xbox-360)

The uShare configuration, `/etc/ushare.conf`, is easy enough to setup and well documented online in a number of forums.  The issue seems to be the encoding... or perhaps Skifta can share images and music with XBox?

At any rate, I would expect to be able to select my Ubuntu (12.10) PC from the xbox, which I can do, and play movies, which are listed but not playable.

EDIT: I just tried removing the audio on one of the videos that was partially playing.  I tried to played the new video only this time it didn't work at all.  This is what I used:

```
avconv -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -an output.m4v
```

Other than changing from `.mp4` to `m4v` I'm not sure why it wouldn't work :-/

Here are the properties of the partially working video from `ffmpeg -i input.mp4`:

```
Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 180000.00 (180000/1) -> 90000.00 (180000/2)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'input.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isom3gp4
    creation_time   : 1946-07-11 02:03:10
  Duration: 00:03:08.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 7706 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline), yuv420p, 1280x720, 7599 kb/s, PAR 65536:65536 DAR 16:9, 28.47 fps, 90k tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1946-07-11 02:03:10
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, mono, s16, 96 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1946-07-11 02:03:10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2008463) out of many that finally answers my question.

Using `avconv` I can convert videos to dvd (?) format.  I removed scaling `-vf scale=720:480`.  Maybe I can replace mp2 with mp3/4?

```
avconv -i INPUT.m4v -f dvd -target ntsc-dvd -b 5000k -r 29.97 -acodec mp2 -ac 2 -ar 48000 -ab 192k OUTPUT.avi
```

This works very well on the XBox 360 however those videos will not work on Android so perhaps I will investigate transcoding next.